# Decoding JSON in Perl. JSON output as multiple lines

Tags: json, perl

How can I use perl to process JSON, so that instead of one line several lines are output as a structure?

```
my $json_string = '{"status":"success","answer":{"status":"success","result":{"full_fqdn":"example.com","result":"blablabla","php_version":"8.0","cgi":"disabled"}}}';
```

I want to get a result like the one on this output:

```
"status": "success",
"answer": {
    "status": "success",
    "result": {
        "full_fqdn": "example.com",
        "result": "blablabla",
        "php_version": "8.0",
        "cgi": "disabled"
    }
}
```

I don't quite understand the proper use of JSON to convert the output this way. Thank you!

Comment: I often just let the Perl module do whatever it wants and pretty print it later with something like `jq -r .`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSON::PP](https://perldoc.pl/JSON::PP) is a core module. The `pretty` method enables the indenting and spaces around colons. You can control the details with `indent`, `indent_length`, `space_before`, and `space_after`.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use JSON::PP;

my $json_string = '{"status":"success","answer":{"status":"success","result":{"full_fqdn":"example.com","result":"blablabla","php_version":"8.0","cgi":"disabled"}}}';

my $j = 'JSON::PP'->new->pretty;
print $j->encode($j->decode($json_string));
```

If you need faster processing, install [Cpanel::JSON::XS](https://perldoc.pl/Cpanel::JSON::XS) from CPAN.